# Active Directory - Certificate Based Authentication - Multiple certificates for user

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, active-directory

First, I have very limited knowledge about AD.

Problem: I authenticating users on AD using user certificates. I want to authenticate user on various devices (including mobile devices). Each will generate its own certificate via a CA. The CA is tied up with AD, so user authenticates on AD via certificates.

On the question is: Can a user account on AD hold multiple certificate for a single user. Because in my case the private key will not be share between devices (Devices will connect with CA to retrieve its own identity cert)

Please help

Answer (score 6):

In the Microsoft / Active Directory world, there are several ways by which certificate-based authentication may happen, but the short answer is: yes, a user can have several certificates.

In IIS terminology, that is called "certificate mapping", with the option [clientCertificateMappingAuthentication](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/clientcertificatemappingauthentication) (not to be confused with [iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication)). There are two methods by which a given client certificate can be mapped unto a user AD account:

- The account in the AD may contain a copy of the certificate (not the private key) in its `userCertificate` attribute.
- The AD server may extract the UPN from the validated client certificate and use that as account name.

Since the `userCertificate` attribute is multi-valued, it can contain several certificates, so this works with what you are looking for. The second kind of mapping can be intricate to set up (the AD server must also have a certificate of its own, and there is a complex game with the "enterprise NTAuth certificate store") but means that a virtually infinite number of certificates, not known in advance, can map to a given user account.

Comment: For anyone coming across this answer in the future, `clientCertificateMappingAuthentication` is NOT enabled by default in IIS 7.0 and later. Scroll down on the Microsoft page that @TomLeek linked to and you can find instructions on how to enable it.